# Python requests and variable payload

Tags: python, python-requests

Reticulated members,

I am attempting to use a GET method that is supported against the endpoint. However, I am using python and wanting to pass the user raw_input that is assigned to a variable:

```
uid = raw_input('Enter username: ')
payload = {'q': %s} % uid
```

where 'q' is the key and '%s' is the value for the query string. PS is throwing a syntax error pointing to %s.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: why not just  `payload = {'q': uid}` ?

Comment: That was returning an ill formatted URL when I printed it, but its just worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%` is a string operator, you are attempting to use it on a dict. also you are passing `%s` as is and not as a string `'%s'`

what you can do is either

```
payload = {'q': uid}
```

or if you insist on using formatting

```
payload = {'q': '%s'% uid}
```