# Python request invalid message

Tags: python, http, python-requests, atom-editor

I am new to Python and am trying to make a post request. I am running into a problem when assigning a variable within the payload of the request. When removing my variable and simply placing a value, the request works fine, but when I try to swap the hard value for my variable, I receive the error

`{"error":{"type":"validation","message":"Invalid message"}}`

I have followed the following articles, but none seem to help my case

https://realpython.com/python-requests/#the-message-body

[Python requests and variable payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463302/python-requests-and-variable-payload)

Here is the code snippet I have. The variable *p* is found in the payload after "pagination"

```
import requests

p = 3
url = "someURL"

payload = "{\r\n\"filters\": {\r\n\"date_from\":\"2011-09-15\",\r\n\"date_to\":\"2019-11-20\"\r\n},\r\n\"pagination\":{\r\n\t\"page\": p,\r\n\t\"limit\":100\r\n}\r\n}"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic someAuth'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

I understand that the payload is not recognizing my variable as an integer, but I am not sure how I can pass the variable through. The end goal is to run multiple iterations of the POST request and increment the variable for each iteration. I need to capture the response data so using Postman for this task isn't possible.

Thank you

Comment: if you want to send JSON data then use `json=` instead of `data=` and then `payload` can be normal dictionary instead of string. And `requests` should automatically add header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: `p` in your payload is only normal char - not value from variable `p` - you would have to use string formationg - "`{}".format(p)` - or `f-string` - `f"{p}"` - to put value in string. Maybe better create normal dictionary and use `json=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `p` in your `payload` is only normal char - not value from variable `p`

You would have to use string formatting

```
payload = '"page": {}'.format(p)
```

or `f-string`

```
payload = f'"page": {p}'
```

to put value in string.

BTW: you can put all text in `' '` if you have to use `" "` inside text

---

Maybe better create normal dictionary and use `json=` - it will convert it to string and add header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. And you can easily set next page in next request

```
payload['pagination']['page'] += 1
```

---

```
import requests

p = 3
url = "someURL"

payload = {
    "filters": {
        "date_from": "2011-09-15",
        "date_to": "2019-11-20",
    },
    "pagination":  {
        "page": p,
        "limit": 100,
    }
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic someAuth'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

print(response.content) # encoded data 
#print(response.text)

# next page

payload['pagination']['page'] += 1

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

print(response.content) # encoded data 
#print(response.text)
```

Comment: Creating a normal dictionary has worked wonders. I was also unaware that this would automatically provide me with the content type too! Thank you very much for your help :)